# Web Hosting: GitHub Pages Not Displaying HTML, CSS, and JS Files

Tags: javascript, html, github, hosting

I am new to github and webpage dev in general.  I built a simple webpage (with html, css, and js) that I'm trying to publish in github.io

The website works when I open the index.html file from my local desktop.  But when I push the exact folder / files to my github repository the Github Pages link produces a weird webpage.

Here is the link to my repository: [link](https://github.com/pinzhi000/FSA_guessingGame/tree/master/guessing-game-master)

Here is the link to my github IO webpage: https://pinzhi000.github.io/FSA_guessingGame/

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index.html is in guessing-game-master folder.

Use this link https://pinzhi000.github.io/FSA_guessingGame/guessing-game-master/

Comment: thank you!  Now I know why everyone says the index file should be on the repository and not in any subfolders